# Link broken in duplicate answer flags view

Tags: bug, flagging, tools

In the 10k+ tools for reviewing flags I see this glitch:

> [image]

This link used to work (at least yesterday). I could then click on the link to go to the automatically marked duplicate answer.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190470/duplicate-flag-links-in-10k-tools-are-broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190470/duplicate-flag-links-in-10k-tools-are-broken) has now [been fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/191075/185080). As Jarrod Dixon says there:

> This has been fixed and the question links now have their titles in the text.